# Compatible, active, open-source jQuery Gallery

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I am looking for a jQuery gallery and want to be sure that this is compatible with all major browsers, well-documented, and preferably evolving as jQuery evolves. So preferably well-established, larger projects. I have found many galleries, but it is difficult to find the ones that comply with this. Many I have seen have not been changed since 2009. So my question is which are the larger, more established jQuery gallery projects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very recommendable is '[Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/)' IMO. It's well documented, works nicely and the last commit on Github is from January 10th.

Comment: Thanks, this was also the one I found and liked before. Any other ones out there like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check these out:
http://www.queness.com/post/222/10-jquery-photo-gallery-and-slider-plugins
http://www.webanddesigners.com/15-jquery-slideshow-and-plugins
http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/

Comment: Thanks, but many of those are not maintained anymore. With those large lists it is hard to separate the larger projects from smaller ones.